# What's the expression for the port of boarding of a flight?

Tags: terminology

What would be an appropriate formal expression to describe the place from which the plane is going to take off?

For e.g. a flight travels from London, Heathrow (LHR) to New Delhi, Delhi Indira Gandhi International Airport (DEL).

**Terms I am thinking of are:**

- 1) Port of departure (LHR), city of departure (London)
- 2) Port of boarding (LHR), city of boarding (London)
  On the itinerary, usually short forms are used and the airport and city from which the plane is going to take off are listed under a column named 'DEP'.

But is there a term used in the airline industry for this?

Comment: Among the definitions you are suggestinig, Port of departure seems the only valid option:https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=port+of+boarding%2Cport+of+departure%2C+city+of+departure%2C+city+of+boading&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cport%20of%20departure%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccity%20of%20departure%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Departure airport may be an alternative:https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=departure+airport%2Cairport+of+departure&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdeparture%20airport%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cairport%20of%20departure%3B%2Cc0

Comment: In airline ticketing terms it is _origin_, _destination_ is your final airport and any stops in between are _intermediate_.

Comment: Ah, that was the word I had in mind. Thank you, @Frank.

Comment: I don't recall seeing *port* used in an airline environment. Except, remarkably, in those terms *port and starboard*, the continuation of which I find astonishing in the airline age.

Comment: @WS2: I vaguely recall the word port being used on immigration forms.

Comment: @Sathyaish Yes, on reflection, *port of entry, port of exit* may be generic names that cover both sea-ports and airports, for some immigration documents etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is *[embarkation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/embarkation)* (embarcation) port.Embark: to go aboard a vessel or aircraft, as at the start of a journey.

Comment: I think *embarkation* is a bit dated. Goes back to the steamship days.

Comment: @WS2 The last time I went through Heathrow Airport it is still used: Disembarkation Cards arrivals have to fill!

Comment: Ah! Disembarkation cards are a government form. And the government is always decades behind the times. However, in fairness to them, I suppose 'disembarkation' has a legal/procedural meaning for immigration law purposes. It describes the moment of arrival in the country.

Comment: @WS2 Well brother I do agree with your remarks about governments being behind the times I am afraid, but I must say that Embarkation and Disembarkation are still also used by countries I visited which were former British colonies: Kenya, Hong Kong and Singapore!

Comment: Yes. Their governments are behind the times too! Seriously, I think at an immigration admin. level the words *embarkation* and *disembarkation* are important. I don't think airlines use them, but hat-off to you if you prove me wrong.

Comment: @WS2 You are quite right sir! I got it now.